# Can we prevent the Higgs field interaction with particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, experimental-physics, higgs, technology

if not why?
is it possible in future?
Because if it is possible there may be chance of more advance invention

Comment: You might as well ask this for any particles or fields and the answer is still obviously no.

Comment: Higgs field interaction is responsible for the mass generation of W,Z bosons, which are carrier of weak nuclear force and effectively enables nucleon beta-decay. Without beta decay radioactive isotope would not be able to gradually step into more stable isotope/atom versions and (my guess) would be forced into rapid breakdown. This for sure would affect metal-rich star formation and then planet formation. The universe as we see it now probably would not exist in that case.  So preventing Higgs field interaction is like preventing furnace in beaking bread.

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no physical mechanism known that would allow this.